# jQuery each function with if stament

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am building a function to validate forms, which I can use for upcoming projects.
The second if stament is not working, I can't figure out why.

```
$('.submit').click(function() {  

    var hasError = false,
        emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,
        form = $('form'),
        radio_check = $('.tick .test'),
        input = $('input:not(.submit)'),
        emailaddressVal = $("#email").val(),
        email = $('#email');

        $('form input:not(.submit)').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

                if(!email.val() == '') {
                        email.css('background-color', '#faa');
                }
            }

        });
});
```

Comment: Define "not working"?

Comment: use triple = operator unless you want type coercion. i.e. ===

Comment: It's not applying the the following: email.css('background-color', '#faa');

Comment: Any time you find yourself writing "not working" in a technical question, backspace over it and say: *Exactly* what you expect to happen, *exactly* what's happening instead, and why that seems wrong to you.

Comment: And the `!=` operator would be better than `!a==b`.

Comment: You don't seem to be returning false or preventing the default action, are you sure the form isn't posting back to the server before you can see the impact of your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kMZeW/2/ full code

Comment: @Alex Your fiddle works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your meaning is to check that the email field is not empty, so you should do:

```
if(!email.val()) { } //-> not falsey
```

Or

```
if(email.val() === '') { } //-> is empty
```

Comment: or possibly `if(email.val() === '')`. But yours is more 'proper'

Comment: @CraigTaub Or possibly not, since checking that it's **not** an empty string isn't the same as checking that it is an empty string.

Comment: true @AnthonyGrist (why i said above was better ) specially with JS and its MANY truthly and falsy values.

Comment: It's not just "better" it's the only one that's correct, unless you want to do `if(email.val() === '') {// do nothing} else {// do something}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(email.val() === '') {...}
```

or

```
if(!email.val()) {...}
```